# Getting Undefined when trying to get Value from Input box built thru jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<input value='Rename' type='button'  onclick='RenameGlobalPhase({$row['id']});'
<span id='renameGlobalPhase{$row['id']}'>" . $row['phase'] . "</span>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
function RenameGlobalPhase(id)// {{{
{
    var phase = $('#renameGlobalPhase' + id).html();
    $('#renameGlobalPhase' + id).replaceWith("<input id='#renameGlobalPhase" + id + "' type='text' onblur='SaveNewPhaseName(" + id + ");' value='" + phase + "' />");
    $('#renameGlobalPhase' + id).focus();
} // }}}

function SaveNewPhaseName(id)// {{{
{
    var newPhase = $('#renameGlobalPhase' + id).val();  
    alert(newPhase);
    $('#renameGlobalPhase' + id).replaceWith('<span>' + newPhase + '</span>');
} // }}}
```

So when user clicks the `input` button above, I turn a `span` next to it into an `input` field so user can rename the value.  And in `onblur`  (newly created from jQuery for that new `input` field), I want to save the new value and return back to `span`.

The alert shows an `undefined` value.  Can anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the `id`

Change

```
.replaceWith("<input id='#renameGlobalPhase" + id + "'
```

to

```
.replaceWith("<input id='renameGlobalPhase" + id + "'
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24tpc/)

Comment: Thanks.  Just a bad typo that killed everything.